# Qt Phonon MediaObject conversion error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, media, phonon

I want to play some WAV files, but I have error C2664 in Visual Studio:

```
error C2664: 'Phonon::MediaObject::setCurrentSource' : conversion error from'const char [24]' to 'const Phonon::MediaSource &'
```

This is the code:

```
Phonon::MediaObject *media_object_;

media_object_ = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
media_object_->setCurrentSource("/sounds/startsound.wav");
media_object_->play();
```

Error   11  error C2664: 'Phonon::MediaObject::setCurrentSource' : no se puede convertir el parámetro 1 de 'const char [24]' a 'const Phonon::MediaSource &'    c:\Naali\devgit\naali\UiModule\Inworld\View\TTSChatWidget.cpp   105 UiModule

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setCurrentSource()` function takes a `MediaSource` object by const-reference. There is no constructor for `MediaSource` that takes a `const char *` (a null terminated byte string). You will probably need to create a temporary object of `QString` with your path and pass it to a `MediaSource` (possibly temporary) and use it to create your . The second example of MSDN documentation on [C2664](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd%28VS.71%29.aspx) explains this.

```
media_object_->setCurrentSource(MediaSource(QString("/sounds/startsound.wav")));
```

Comment: I was using it because it's here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-mediaobject.html

Comment: Where do I have to declare MediaSource?

Comment: Just include the appropriate headers for `MediaSource` and `QString`. Also, note what the `setCurrentSource` documentation says: _You can just as well use a QUrl or QString (for a local file) here._